# Difference Between SQL Server Access from .Net Versus Qt

Tags: c#, c++, sql-server, qt

I have two applications that both access the same database. One is written in C# and using .NET services to connect to the database; the other is written in C++ and uses Qt to connect. I am not an expert on the behind-the-scenes mechanisms, so I'm floundering a bit with a specific issue. The problem I'm having is that the .NET application works fine remotely, but the Qt application does not.

The issue is caused by a server-side problem where there's some weirdness with Windows authentication. The .NET application is connecting without triggering Windows authentication, but the Qt application apparently is using Windows authentication despite every effort I've made to avoid it. Obviously, if the server were fixed--which it hopefully will be--the issue goes away, but I have an additional application I need to create, which needs to provide access to a larger number of users and I can't deal with Windows authentication for all of them, so I need to figure out how to avoid the Windows authentication altogether.

The .NET application uses the SqlDataAdapter class with a connection string in the format "Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog=nnnn;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=uuuuuu;Password=ppppp".

The Qt application uses the QSqlDatabase class and a connection string in the format "DRIVER={SQL SERVER};Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Database=nnnn;User ID=uuuuuu;Password=ppppp".

I've tried using the "Data Source" format with the Qt application and it doesn't work. I've experimented with various parameters suggested in other posts (Trusted_Connection and Integrated Security), and regardless of what I do, the Qt application always uses Windows authentication or fails altogether. When it fails, the error messages indicate unrecognized parameters in the connection string.

I've spent hours searching and experimenting. For the upcoming application I need to write, using C# and .NET is a viable approach, but I'm much more familiar with Qt and will get the application written far faster using that approach. It seems to me that I should be able to connect to the server without going through Windows authentication, but I'm at a loss right now. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: so where is the problem with the .NET approach? a useful resource for the various sql connection string configurations [can be found here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/). to attract useful answers. include a minimal, complete example and all details about the errors/exceptions you get, "doesn't work" is too vague. for newer versions of sql server, mixed mode is no longer the default, so it could be a serverside configuration issue as well.

Comment: try using ODBC instaed of QSqlDatabase

Comment: @dlatikay, as I said, the .NET code works; I need to write a new application and because I'm more familiar with Qt, it will go faster if I use Qt, so what I'm trying to do is get the same connection logic to work in Qt.

Comment: @Steve, how does that translate in Qt classes? I don't understand what you're suggesting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the other questions on this subject reported that when he printed the username after the connection failure, it was his local username, not the one he'd specified in QSqlDatabase::setUserName. In his case, he added the username and password to the connection string (as in my original example) to get it working. His example also used "user_id" whereas mine had "User ID". (I do not know if the spaces and underscores in these things are interchangeable, but I'm getting that impression.)

When I printed the QSqlDatabase object's username after my connection failure, mine was blank, regardless of what I put in the connection string. I got neither the username I specified in the connection string, nor my local login.

His code that didn't work also called QSqlDatabase::setUserName and QSqlDatabase::setPassword separately from the connection string. While it didn't work for him, I hadn't tried that, so I did, and it works just fine.

So in his case, putting the authentication in the connection string worked; in my case, specifying the authentication on the QSqlDatabase object worked.

While I'm still confused as to why these things are happening, my problem is resolved, and I can proceed to write my new application using Qt, which will be much faster to develop than getting up to speed on all of the .NET technology.